# ASP.NET code rendered in Chrome looks different

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I was wondering why the following code:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="DropDown1" runat="server" Width="30px" AutoCompleteMode=None 
AutoPostBack=false DropDownStyle=DropDown EnableViewState="True">
</asp:ComboBox>&nbsp;<asp:Literal ID="myid1" runat="server" Text="Days"></asp:Literal>
```

produces the combobox with label "Days" to the right off of it in IE9 and FireFox but when I run it using Chrome the "Days" label appears below the combo box?

How do I make it to be drawn to the right off the combo box like the rest of the browsers?

Comment: Is this code the only code on the page? Are there any containing elements that would cause the label to wrap?

Comment: @ahmd0 - There are many things which will surprise you when these things (css/html) are not learned properly. Learn html/css from the scratch.

Comment: Well, thank you for "constructive" comment, AVD :) As for other code, then no, I added it into an empty web application project (just as I showed it above) and it behaves exactly as I explained. So, what CSS needs to be adjusted to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: An accurate answer to your question would require your entire HTML and CSS to be posted, since HTML and CSS allow the drawing of comboboxes and labels in an infinite number of ways. AVD's point that he alludes to is that if you're uncertain of how to do this, which itself is an extremely basic HTML / CSS task, you may be better off learning the fundamentals of HTML / CSS in order to benefit yourself in the long term

Comment: @ahmd0, post your html (from view-source) and CSS. Even better way would be reproduce the problem on jsfiddle.net and post the link.

Comment: @ AVD, @ Jon P, @ Shan Plourde, @ VinayC - Thanks, and please read my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up the Combo Box is not part of the "Standard" asp.net controls. I'm assuming you are using the asp.net AJAX Toolkit for this. As the Combo box is a compound control it does not render "Clean HTML" eg:

```
<select id="DropDown1"></select> Days
```

Instead it renders:

```
<div id="DropDown1" style="display:inline-block;">    
    <table id="DropDown1_Table" 
           class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" 
           cellspacing="0" 
           cellpadding="0" 
           border="0" 
           style="display:inline-block;border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;position:relative;top:5px;">    
        <tr>    
             <td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer">
                <input name="DropDown1$TextBox" 
                       type="text" 
                       id="DropDown1_TextBox" 
                       autocomplete="off" 
                       style="width:30px;" />
             </td>
             <td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer">
                 <button id="DropDown1_Button" 
                         type="button"
                         style="visibility:hidden;"></button>
             </td>    
        </tr>    
     </table>
     <input type="hidden" 
            name="DropDown1$HiddenField" 
            id="DropDown1_HiddenField" 
            value="-1" />    
</div>&nbsp;Days
```

Which for me in chrome 14 displays with the Days in the same line as the drop down.

The thing to note is the div wrapping up the combo box control. Either the version on chrome you are using is ignoring the `display:inline-block;` style or you have some CSS somewhere that is somehow overriding this.

Maybe look at using the standard controls and use [jQuery and page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to roll your own combo box, or better still look at [FlexBox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox).

Which version of chrome on which OS is causing the issue?

If you don't need AJAX functionality just use the standard ASP:Dropdown control.

**UPDATE:**

Using Microsoft's [Combo Box Sample page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/combobox/combobox.aspx) reproduces your issue in Chrome. Looking at the rendered code it is different in IE and Chrome. This leads me to believe I have a different version of the tool kit to yourself and Microsoft (probably older!)

IE uses `display:inline-block` while chrome renders `display:inline` which would be causing the display anomaly.

To work around the issue with the version of the toolkit you are using, I would try the following:

```
<div style="display:inline-block">    
   <asp:ComboBox ID="DropDown1" runat="server" Width="30px" AutoCompleteMode=None AutoPostBack=false DropDownStyle=DropDown EnableViewState="True">
   </asp:ComboBox>
</div>
&nbsp;<asp:Literal ID="myid1" runat="server" Text="Days"></asp:Literal>
```

Comment: Yes, Jon, wrapping the <asp:ComboBox> block in the div with the inline-block solves the issue. And even though I makred it as an answer, unfortunately it's too late for me to change it from my <table> approach in my actual code. I wish this post didn't sit unanswered for several days...

Answer (score 0):

I guess no one gets the "correct answer" check for this one.

Here's how I was able to "patch it" -- again, good ol' table came to rescue...

```
<table width="100%" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom" width="1%"><asp:ComboBox ID="DropDown1" runat="server" Width="30px" AutoCompleteMode=None  AutoPostBack=false DropDownStyle=DropDown EnableViewState="True"></asp:ComboBox></td>
<td valign="bottom" width="99%">&nbsp;<asp:Literal ID="myid1" runat="server" Text="Days"></asp:Literal></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

On the side note, I don't know guys how you can use that ASP.NET & VS2010. Both are such a headache and I'm so glad that my short stint with it is over!!!

Comment: Well, no offense, but that's a pretty "hacky" and ugly way to solve an issue that could have been fixed with a line or two of CSS. Also, you can accept your own answer after a couple of days. Just one tip: *always* put quotes around your attribute values -- you don't have quotes around some of yours.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Cory. I agree, this is a "very hacky" solution, but after all, ASP.NET is exactly that. I'm coming from a PHP world and have always composed my HTMLs myself with the use of CSS, but with this ASP.NET it is virtually impossible to do. I looked into a resulting HTML via "view source" command and it's monstrocity what the code becomes! Anyways, I spent several days digging into the depth of CSS/ASP.NET to see what could be the reason and eventually gave up. On the side note, why do I need to wrap attributes into quotes? Does HTML spec say so???

Comment: As somebody who has worked professionally with both PHP and ASP.NET, most of what you say is simply not true. It is just as easy to control the layout of an ASP.NET site with CSS as it is for PHP. Yes, ASP.NET generates bloated markup, but there are several things you can do to prevent it from being a "monstrocity." Wrapping attribute values is just **good practice**, like using semicolons in JavaScript. Quotes are not always required, but it's been years since it was acceptable to omit them.

Comment: As I said above I prefer to write my own HTML/CSS and not let some Microsoft creation do it for me... (Again it may be my opinion only and I might be alone on this one.)

Comment: Then maybe you should try ASP.NET MVC2/MVC3, which doesn't use server controls. You control example how your HTML looks.

Answer (score 0):

"why do I need to wrap attributes into quotes"

Yes, you do need to pick up a good book on HTML / CSS and study it.

Comment: I agree, but probably should be a comment.

Comment: I prefer not to waste time for adding quotes in HTML mark-up for simple things such as numbers. If you prefer to do that, good for you, it won't make any difference in the final outcome (except produce a larger file.)

Comment: Adding quotes is a waste of time? Don't you think it pays to be consistent? The W3 HTML specification recommends using quotes. They are *required* in the XHTML specification and in every XML-based specification. It seems wrong to treat HTML differently just because you can.